# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Exception when I try to close ElasticSearch client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

When I try to close an ElasticSearch client using the Java API 6.0 I get the following exception on the client.close() call:

```
Exception in thread "elasticsearch[_client_][generic][T#1]" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.config()Lio/netty/bootstrap/BootstrapConfig;
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.lambda$stopInternal$7(Netty4Transport.java:390)
at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.close(IOUtils.java:89)
at org.elasticsearch.common.lease.Releasables.close(Releasables.java:36)
at org.elasticsearch.common.lease.Releasables.close(Releasables.java:46)
at org.elasticsearch.common.lease.Releasables.close(Releasables.java:51)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.stopInternal(Netty4Transport.java:373)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.lambda$doStop$14(TcpTransport.java:927)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:569)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using exactly the same code that is presented as an example in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) of the Java API 6.0 for ElasticSearch:

```
        // on startup
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    // on shutdown
    client.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

A `NoSuchMethodError` indicates an issue with your dependencies. The Java API 6.0 documentation points to this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

A transitive dependency of the one above is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

In version 4.1.13.Final the class `io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap` has a method `config()` with return value `BootstrapConfig`:

```
public final BootstrapConfig config()
  {
    return this.config;
  }
```

Please check with `mvn dependency:tree` that you are using the correct version of `io.netty:netty-transport`.

Comment: In my pom.xml file I have the following dependencies:

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Per siom's answer, you need to use `mvn dependency:tree` and see exactly what maven is resolving, rather than just trusting what you configured.

Answer (score 0):

I encounted same problems in running my test code while using es 5.5.1. I resolved it by add maven dependency below:

> io.netty
>   netty-all 4.1.25.Final
>   test